# how to exclude a combination while doing regex search?

Tags: c#, regex, search, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I would like to exclude one combination while I do regex search. How is it possible?

**Input example:**

```
if("invalid"=key,if("A01"=key,true,false),if("B01"=key,true,false))
```

**Desired output:**

regex match should  return true only if at least any one  combination like `"{}"=key` except `"invalid"=key` is present(i.e it should skip this specific combination.every combination will end with =key tag)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to tidy up this question and use code markup more appropriately, its hard to read and unclear what you are asking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a lookaround check while matching the `"` + 1 or more chars other than `"` + `"=key` substring:

```
var isMatched = Regex.IsMatch(s, "\"(?!invalid\")[^\"]+\"=key\\b");
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%22%28%3F!invalid%22%29%5B%5E%22%5D%2B%22%3Dkey%5Cb&i=if%28%22invalid%22%3Dkey%2Cif%28%22A01%22%3Dkey%2Ctrue%2Cfalse%29%2Cif%28%22B01%22%3Dkey%2Ctrue%2Cfalse%29%29)

The `"(?!invalid")[^"]+"=key\b` regex means:

- `"` - a double quote
- `(?!invalid")` - not followed with `invalid"` substring
- `[^"]+` - 1 or more chars other than double quotes
- `"=key` - a `"=key` substring
- `\b` - word boundary, no letter/digit/`_` after `key` allowed.